How can I get a review from a different moderator?
I am starting to feel as if moderator Voltage Spike♦ has some sort of vendetta against my question "How might one attempt to recover a fully drained NiMH cell?". Currently:

I've taken various suggestions to edit it, which appears to have steadily improved it;
the question itself has at least two upvotes;
there are two answers both of which I find to be good and useful, both of which also have at least two upvotes each; and
there have been several rounds of re-open votes, the most recent completed of which was one for re-open, and one for close from Voltage Spike♦.
it currently has two active votes to re-open.

But Voltage Spike♦ has now as a moderator unilaterally closed my question three times in a row, if I'm reading the timeline correctly. He's given only extremely vague reasons for closing it, and is unwilling to tell me what the difference is between my question and substantially similar ones such as this such that mine should be closed but that one should remain open.
Is it possible to get a different moderator or two to review this close decision?

On top of each question is the reason why it was closed, please read that.
Has it occurred to you that you are creating a lot of work for the moderation queues? I was not the only person that closed your question. There were originally three people other than myself. The question does not conform with this rule, more specifically the rule here listed in the help center which you assumedly have not read. But probably should have before posting a question here, especially if you are going to contest said question:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic


This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals,
students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about
electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include
electronics, physical computing, and those working with
microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best
Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent
datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally
covers …
a specific electronics design problem
the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
a communication scheme
the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications


The question simply does not fall into these categories, the mission of SE is to build a repository of good questions, this is not a good fit for this site. Quit creating more work for the moderation team which tirelessly volunteers to create a safe place where people can post good questions. Please stop badgering the moderators and give it a rest.

Your assumption that I have not read that "on-topic" document is wrong; I've read it several times. That's one of the reasons I would like another moderator to look at it. And I have discussed your specific points in comments on your other meta answer, which you have not addressed, including a pointer to a specific question very similar to mine, and about the same devices, but with much less detail, which you (by not closing it) do appear to believe is on topic for the site.

As for "more work for the moderation team," you are free to leave the "work" on this question to another moderator, and I wish you would do so.

By way of showing your interpretation of those on-topic examples as a strict limit is far too strict, here are five questions with >100 upvotes that are all clearly not on any of the above topics. (I agree with others that all of these are good questions, and appropriate for this site.)
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/20023/15390
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/67975/15390
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/110478/15390
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1980/15390
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3578/15390

(Note in particular that mine involves electromagnetic forces and circuits, and none of the above do.)
